# TypeError: one() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: matplotlib, pyqt5

PyCharm return "TypeError: one() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"
I've searched for the whole night but still can't figure it out T T
I think the bug is from **mpl_connect()**, because when I use the **connect() from pyqtBoundSignal** it works

```
"""test.py"""
class forTest(QWidget):
    signalTest = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super(forTest, self).__init__()
        canvas = FigureCanvas(figure(facecolor="blue"))
        # I got the following from other answer, but still not working
        self.cid = canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.one)

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        layout.addWidget(canvas)

    def one(self):
        self.signalTest.emit()
        print("emit()")

"""receice.py"""
class RTest(object):
    def handle_signal(self):
        print("get successfully")

"""main.py"""
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    tt = forTest()
    rr = RTest()
    tt.signalTest.connect(rr.handle_signal)

    tt.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [`mpl_connect()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/backend_bases_api.html#matplotlib.backend_bases.FigureCanvasBase.mpl_connect) documentation:

> **func : *callable***
> The callback function to be executed, which must have the signature:
>
> `def func(event: Event) -> Any`

So, `one()` *must* have a further argument:

```py
    def one(self, event):
        self.signalTest.emit()
        print("emit()")
```

The reason for which the direct signal connection works is that PyQt is able to discard positional arguments when they exceed the connected signal (or function) argument count.